# Backbone.js accessing another view function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm developing an application with Backbone.js

I have 2 view and I want use a function defined in other view:

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    resultsView.myFunction();
  }

})


var resultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  myFunction: function(){
    alert('test')
  }
})
```

How I can do it?

Comment: In general, You don't want to do that. You'll end up with spaghetti code. If it's a general function, abstract it out. If the function really does have to do with something that resultsView should be concerned with, then listen for changes in the model or trigger an event on formView that resultsView listens to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not use events?

[routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/)

Answer (score 5):

You're doing it the opposite way. You can do a `base view` that other views can extend and implement such as:

```
/** Any Views that inherit from this View can use the myFunction() */
var BaseView = Backbone.View ({
  myFunction : function(param) {
      alert(param);
  }
});

/** Inherit from the base view above */
var ChildView = BaseView.extend({
  initialize : function(){
      this.myFunction('test');
  }
});

var instanceView = new ChildView({});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Backbone.View.extend`, you are creating a `class`. In order to use the class, you need to create an `instance` using the `new` operator. It's conventional to start class names with a Capital letter, and instance variable names with a small letter, so I'll use that naming convention in the following samples:

```
//declare view class
var ResultsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  myFunction: function(){
    alert('test')
  }
});
```

Create an instance of the class, and pass it into your `FormView`:

```
var resultsView = new ResultsView();
var formView = new FormView({ resultsView: resultsView });
```

Access the passed argument in the `FormView.initialize`:

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options){
    options.resultsView.myFunction();
  }
});
```